# Post archive is not using the assigned template

Tags: templates

Background:

- In a custom theme's Settings > Reading > Posts page, I have designated all posts to be output on a page called "News and Events"
- I created a new page which is blank except for the page title (News and Events) and assigned it to a template called "News"
- I added "News" to the menu and linked to `/news-and-events`
- I created a template in my theme called `news.php` which has the required header and the typical code to display the content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: News
etc.
```

- Note: some of the posts are categorized and some are "uncategorized"

The problem is the News and Events page uses `home.php` by default. If I delete `home.php` it uses `index.php`. Question: why doesn't it use `news.php`?

I've studied the obligatory WordPress template chart but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: why doesn't it use news.php?

This is due to a design decision.

If you look at the diagram for the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2023/10/template-hierarchy-scaled.jpeg), you will notice that the **Blog Home** page type (black box) has a line connecting directly to the **home.html** primary template (blue box) with no options in between.

If you go to the Edit page to update the page (News and Events) selected under the admin **Settings > Reading > Post page** by changing the template, you will see this warning message:

> The posts page template cannot be changed.

When met with this warning message, you will also see a link inviting you to edit the Home template.

This [WordPress support blog](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/static-front-page/#creating-your-static-front-page) says this about the page selected for the **Post page** option:

> Don’t add any content to this Page because it will be displaying your recent Posts – not any added content

---

Your goal can be achieved by using the **Settings > Reading > Homepage** option (seen under *A static page (select below)*). The page you choose here can use any page template you wish.

Another option is to use a [Custom Front Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-front-page-templates/). Front page templates are commonly used to display static content.

You can use a secondary [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) loop with either a static **Homepage** or Custom Front Page to display a list of posts (like you would see on home.html). Take note of [differences regarding pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-front-page-templates/#pagination) though. WordPress documentation says:

> None of the WordPress [Previous / Next page link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links) functions work with a static front page.

Instead, you need to use [WP_Query pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) options.

Comment: I think I get it: whatever page is set for "Settings > Reading > Post page" is considered the Blog Home, hence the line drawn to home.php/home.hrml (this site was built pre-FSE). Very helpful.

Comment: Yes. It's as if the chosen page were a "dummy" page whose only purpose is to provide a database post ID to represent the blog. But, regardless of the ID, it's always home.php/home.html that will be used.

Comment: Brilliant. WordPress's use of templates is still a mystery to me. I'll look at the support blog, but can you recommend any other resources?

Comment: I recently provided this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/420146#420150) to a question about templates. It has several links. I can summarize like this: Permalink structures are used to create rewrite rules. Rewrite rules take a pretty permalink URL and convert it into a plain URL with a query string. Query string parameters are used to decide the template type. The template type is used with the Template Hierarchy to choose the template file. E.g. if *category_name* is a query string parameter, the template type is *category* (an archive page). See my answer for details.

Comment: On the question of the **Blog Home** page, the `wp_posts` database ID that is assigned associates all the other `wp_posts` database fields to the Blog Home page. For example, the `post_name` field (post slug) is used to create the URL for the Blog Home page (e.g. `https://example.com/news-and-events`). The ID is linked to other database tables (e.g. `wp_postmeta`) that can link meta data to the Blog Home page. Meta data can be used to provide data for dynamic changes to the appearance or behavior of the page (e.g. by editing home.php or updating the blocks used in home.html).

Comment: Finally, a technical answer to how this all works. I've added your recently provide answer to my Notion database for easy access.